# How to get super class memberBlocks using Swift Macros?

Tags: ios, swift, macros, wwdc

I'm trying to create swift macros for initializers for inherited classes i should have the members of the super class for super.init() parameters. how to get super class member blocks?

```
@Init
class Car1 {
    var test1: Int
    var test2: Int?
}

@Init
class Car1: Car2 {
    var test1: Int
    var test2: Int?
}
```

It will throw an error because the memberblocks(the attributes) of the superclass is missing

Comment: What is the expected expansion of the macro?

Comment: I'm not sure this can work in the current form, as each `@Init` macro expands separately from the rest, without access to that other context.

Comment: I'm cautious about whether this kind of macro would be a good idea to have or not. Classes intentionally don't have memberwise initializers like structs do, and there's a reason. Objects (instances of classes) aren't just dumb buckets of values. If they were, they could probably have been a struct instead. Objects are meant to have some kind of private state that they mediate access to via methods that implement meaningful business operations. That's not something a memberwise initializer is helper for.

Comment: @vadian The expected Expansion should be init(test1: Int, test2: Int?, test1: Int, test2: Int?) {
        self.test1= test1 self.test2 = test2
        super.init(test1: test1, test2: test2)
    } (usual super init)

Comment: This is not possible, because the macro can see only the scope from after the identifier `@Init` up to the closing brace.